# How to calculate how many days have passed based on two cells values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I am trying to calculate how many days have passed upon receiving a PO after an NTP has been provided. The part I'm struggling with is that sometimes based on an entry there could be a blank in either the NTP Date or the PO Date and I need to calculate a different formula based on that.

[image: Here's my table]

Ideally, I would like it to look something like this in the PO Delay column,

Calculate `[PO DATE]-[NTP Date]`, If [PO DATE] is blank calculate `=TODAY()-[NTP DATE]`,
If [NTP DATE] is blank do nothing

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested IFs:

```
=IF([@[NTP Date]]="","",IF([@[PO Date]]="",TODAY(),[@[PO Date]])-[@[NTP Date]])
```

[image]